# How can I cause multiple absolute positioned divs to be treated as backgrounds?

Tags: css, html

I have a main container div, where all the important content of the site is inserted, 800px wide, centered horizontally.

I need to put multiple absolute positioned divs layered below it (via z-index) and outside its width, without causing extra scrollbars to appear, and without losing the main container scrollbars (so puting overflow:hidden in a wraper won't do).

In other words, I was wondering if it's possible to create divs with different elements inside (videos, images, or text) that could be treated as backgrounds, so that the scrollbars would only appear when the window resizes below the 800px wide (width of the main container), and the rest of the divs would just bleed out (something similar to what [swffit](http://swffit.millermedeiros.com/) causes with an embebed flash movie).

Is there any way to do this via css or javascript?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you put a video below the container div via z-index the video will not be clickable. Do you mind that?

Comment: @SavasVedova
Not at all, I plan to use those videos as "moving backgrounds", autoplaying and looping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way that requires CSS only. I once faced similar problem with [this web site](http://equido.cz/) I created, take a look at the source. The curves by the side are done this way.

Trick is to change positioning of main container to relative with no shift - that causes change of coordinates base, [here is a link](http://css-tricks.com/791-absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/). Than use absolute positioning of the "background divs" to get them outside the main box.

To solve the overflow problem use some extra div wrapper (in my site with id graphic). To specify its width use a range - min-width equal to main box and max-width as total width including the "backgound divs". And to this wrapper set the hidden overflow.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I've checked the code of your site and your explanation, it should work perfectly for what I'm after. I'm not at home right now, but when I get back I'll try it and let you know!

Thanks again!